# XmlSerializer sets null to property after self-closed tag defined as XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

Imagine having XML structure like the following:

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SuperImportant")]
    public SuperImportant SuperImportant { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlElement("Baz")]
    public XmlElement Baz { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("SuperImportant")]
public class SuperImportant
{
    [XmlElement("MegaImportant")]
    public string MegaImportant { get; set; }
}
```

Baz defined as `XmlElement` for some reason.

Now check this code:

```
var template = @"
<Foo>
  <Bar>
    {0}
  </Bar>
  <SuperImportant>
    <MegaImportant>42</MegaImportant>
  </SuperImportant>
</Foo>";

var selfClosed = new StringReader(String.Format(template, "<Baz/>"));    

var openClosePair = new StringReader(String.Format(template, "<Baz></Baz>"));

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));

var o1 = (Foo)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(selfClosed);
Console.WriteLine(o1.SuperImportant == null); // True, it's not there

var o2 = (Foo)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(openClosePair);
Console.WriteLine(o2.SuperImportant == null); // False, it's there
```

As you can see, if some tag, defined as `XmlElement` in class definition appears to be self closed, the element right after its parent tag is `null`ed. How can I configure `XmlSerializer` to treat self-closed tags as open-close pairs?  `SuperImportant` should be deserialized in both cases, but it's not in the former, which is wrong.

Comment: Why do you consider case one as okay, while case two is not ok? I´d expected that regardless if the element before is present in whatever kind, `SuperImportant` should be serialized anyway. I can´t imagine why it should **not** be deserialized after a self-closed `Baz`, while it should be when having a `<Baz></Baz>`. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, of course, `SuperImportant` Should be serialized in both cases, but it's not, that is why I am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mark the property `Baz` with `[XmlAnyElement("Baz")]` like so:

```
[XmlRoot("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlAnyElement("Baz")]
    public XmlElement Baz { get; set; }
}
```

As explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx), this attribute

> Specifies that the member (a field that returns an array of [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) or [XmlNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) objects) contains objects that represent any XML element that has no corresponding member in the object being serialized or deserialized.
>   
> ...
>   You can also apply the XmlAnyElementAttribute to a field that returns a single [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) object. If you do so, you must use the properties and methods of the XmlElement class to recursively iterate through the unknown elements.

Once the attribute is applied, the `Baz` property will correctly capture both the `<Baz/>`  and `<Baz></Baz>` elements without interfering with deserialization of subsequent node(s).  It does seem odd that `[XmlElement("Baz")]` causes the inconsistency you are seeing, but since `[XmlAnyElement("Baz")]` is designed to handle this situation it should be used instead.

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPcuCf).